# How do I dynamically generate dates, taking holidays into account?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to figure out how to generate a series of dates dynamically.  I need to take holidays into account.  I've got an array of dates, but for each member of the date array, I want to compare it against an array of holidays and move the date when necessary.

Anytime there's a holiday, I want to pick the date before that holiday, but I need to take into account situations when there are multi-date holidays (e.g. a Thursday and Friday holiday, or potentially a 3- or 4-day holiday).

Here is my working code, which is currently unable to do what I want; Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
dates = [array of dates]
holidays = [array of holidays]

dates.each do |date|
  adjust_for_holidays(date)
end

def adjust_for_holidays
  n = 0      
  while holidays.include? date  
    n += 1
    date = date - (n-1)
  end
 date
```

Comment: Yes.  It turns out that the code I posted works.  There was nothing wrong with the original code, but my implementation had a flaw.  I like your approach, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
require 'date'

dates = []
(1..28).each do |i|
  dates << Date.new(2012, 02, i) 
end

@holidays = [Date.new(2012, 02, 17), Date.new(2012, 02, 18)]
puts "HOLIDAYS: " + @holidays.inspect

def adjust_for_holidays(date)
  while @holidays.include? date  
    date = date - 1
  end
 date
end

d = dates.collect do |date|
  adjust_for_holidays(date)
end
```

Note that you're setting date = date - (n-1) there and n keeps increasing.

Answer (score 1):

well first your method doesnt have the right number of arguments.  Also dates has to be an instance variable.  I would suggest a hash of holidays where the key is the date and the value is the number of days for that holiday.  For example for presidents day and labor day

```
{'2/18' => 1,
 '9/2'  => 1
}
```

if it includes the date, then you would go whatever value ahead.  something like this

```
def adjust_for_holidays(dates)
  holidays.each do |date, value|
    @date += value if @date.include?(date)
  end
end
```

something like that.  not sure how you're going to add certain number of days into a string date though.  ill let you figure that out :).